# org mode: help!! i’ve collapsed my section and can’t get it back out

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I am using `spacemacs`. This may seem like a joke, but it really is not (but it is kind of funny).

I was typing in org-mode just now, I may have hit some `god-mode key`, and the section I am typing in now ***collapsed into its header*** and **I cannot uncollapse/expand it back open**.

1. Updated typing happens invisibly, but I can’t see anything.
2. My text is still there, because I can see the diff output.
3. Re-loading my saved (spacemacs) layout does nothing.

•  I know this is simple, but a google did not reveal anything.

•  Hitting `tab` or `Enter` on the section header **does nothing**.

Pls help  V.V

Comment: What happens if you say `M-x fundamental-mode RET`? Do you see everything (albeit without pretty colors)? What happens if you save the file and look at it outside emacs (e.g. cat it in an xterm or other terminal emulator)? What happens if (after you save and assuming everything is there) you kill the buffer and reopen the file?

Comment: @NickD Thanks for your kind suggestions. `M-x fundamental-mode RET` indeed showed all the contents, and they are all there. I also have my notes git committed, so I am absolutely certain (`git diff`) that no changes were made due to this weird collapse-situation I encountered. Instead of killing the buffer, I just exited and re-entered `spacemacs`, and re-loaded my layout (`SPC l L <my layout>`) and the .org file is back to normal (phew!).  Thanks again.

Comment: @NickD feel free to post your suggested resolution steps as an answer and I’d be very happy to accept. Best regards

Comment: Well, it's not really an answer, more of a rough roadmap to get you back to solid ground. So I'm glad you got the problem resolved, but I don''t really have an answer to what went wrong.

Comment: @NickD thanks! Got it!. I don’t have enough rep to upvote your comments, but otherwise I would !  Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you toggle on `M-x visible-mode` you would be able to see all of the text, and probably fix the problem.

(Switch the mode off once you're done, to allow org's visibility rules to take effect again.)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 other quick things to try:

1. `C-q` will exit a mode you may have accidentally entered
2. `ESC-u` to undo what you were typing ... but
   beware if you don't save frequently with `:w`- although
   you could `ESC C-r` to redo if too much is
   undone.

Comment: This sounds like advice which is specific to `evil.el`.  As the question included mention of `god-mode` I strongly suspect that they're not using `evil`.

Comment: My mistake. I don't use god-mode and did not consider it especially with a binding to esc